# Executing Monte Carlo method for finding the minimum of f

Tags: python

I am considering a function:

```
f(x) = 1 − exp −(x + 3)2  − 2 exp −(x − 2)2).
```

My question is:

> Write a Python function that inputs a function f, an initial guess x,
>   and a number of iterations N, and does the following: Starting with
>   the initial x, then for N iterations:
>
> 1. generate a normally distributed random number δx
> 2. find the cost f(x + δx). If this is less than the present cost f(x), update x with x + δx. Otherwise leave x unchanged.
> 3. output the final x.

I want to try different initial values of x and see where the algorithm ends up.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

fun = lambda x: 1 - np.exp(-(x+3)**2) - 2*np.exp(-(x-2)**2)

def monteCarlo(costFun = fun, x = 0., N=100, sigma = 1.):

        '''Find a minimum of a function approximately using simulated annealing'''
        cost = costFun(x)
        for j in range(N):
                T = 1. - float(j)/N #Temperature
                dx = np.random.normal(scale = sigma)
                newx = x + dx
                newcost = costFun(newx) 
                p = np.random.random()
                if newcost < cost or p < np.exp(-(newcost-cost)/T):
                        cost = newcost
                        x = newx
                        print('point: ' + str(x) + ', cost = ' + str(cost) + ', T = ' + str(T))
        return
```

Note: I haven't been able to list my code properly, but it starts from: 'import numpy'. (I am relatively new to this forum).

I consider my python code to have no bugs, but I am having difficulty in the final stage to vary the initial values of x.

Any help would be so appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like x is already being varied within your code. Can you  describe your issue in mode detail? Are are you just missing a call at the end to see the results? That would be `monteCarlo()`

Comment: thank you this should have been obvious to me thank you for your help